# Trigger an element click on newly opened browser window using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a web page say **main.jsp**. I am opening a new window using:

`var w=window.open(url);`   which opens **second.jsp** page in **new** browser tab.

I am trying to trigger click of an element, with class **elementToClick**, present on second.jsp using:

```
$(w.document).find('.elementToClick').trigger('click');
```

However, this is not working.

I am able to do DOM Manipulation like:

```
 $(w.document).find('.elementToClick').html('someHtml');
```

but not able to trigger events on it.

Please help me in this. I have read other links related to it but couldn't find a solution to this.

Comment: Try `$(w.document).find('.elementToClick').get(0).click();`

Comment: Thank you Satpal !!! This works ! Dont know why the trigger click was not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `.trigger('click')` will only trigger the click handler associate with the element. *It will not actually click the element.*

You can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the underlying DOM element, then use its `click()` function

```
$(w.document).find('.elementToClick').get(0).click();
```